# UnsubscribePromise not being returned from subscription

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

When I try to create a subscription from a custom pallet, it doesn't return a `UnsubscribePromise` (like the native ones), but returns a `Promise<Codec>`, even though I added a callback as the last parameter, just like explained here: `https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.subs/`

eg: (using `https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fbrainstorm.invarch.network#/explorer`)

```js
// THIS RETURNS A UNSUB
const unsub = api.rpc.chain.subscribeNewHeads((header) => {
  setCurrentBlock(header.number.toNumber());
});

// THIS RETURNS A PROMISE<CODEC>
const promise = api.query.ocifStaking.nextEraStartingBlock((blockNumber: Codec) => {
  setNextEraBlock(blockNumber.toPrimitive() as number);
});
```

If this is intended, why?

If not, how do I define the correct type on my RPC call on the frontend?